# Switching from Windows Insider to the stable release

Tags: windows-10, setup, windows-insider

I signed up to Windows Insider and everytime there is a new release, I usually download the ISO and install it.

Twice a year, a new stable version of Windows is released, I've downloaded the ISO and tried to install it only to find that the only available option is to do a clean install and my online research suggested leaving the Insider program or going back to *an earlier version*.

I do not want that so my question is there a way to "juggle" between stable (normally twice a year) and the more frequent insider builds without having to reinstall Windows every time? I tend to believe, if I understood the comments right, that the reason is that insider builds have a higher build number and installing a stable release would mean installing an **"older"** version.

Comment: What channel are you currently in, Beta or Dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off Windows Insider in your Windows 10 Settings preferences (Updates)  and then wait. At one of the major updates, it will revert to non-insider without the need for a reinstall.

Moving back and forth is not at all practical. I have a separate Insider machine, but I am aware not everyone can do this

From October 20, 2020 (yesterday) it will take some time (about 6 months) to get back to a production release. That is a long time to wait, so an alternative is to back up your machine completely and reinstall production Windows 10 and your applications. Then restore your data.

This will work also.

Comment: So if I wait long enough without updates (which is not the best idea) till the next release, I'll be able to go back to the mainstream build?

Comment: I think if you wait, that should work. 20H2 (very small) was issued October 20 and the next one is some time off.

Comment: @user10191234 - When you opt-out of the Insider Program you will continue to receive Windows Updates for your current channel.  However, if you are on the Beta channel, it will take a good amount of time until you are placed back in the Stable channel.  More information about the current state of your system would be helpful.

Comment: I am using version 2004, build 20231, the Dev channel, I waited till I installed the ISO released on October 20, 2020 on another, its build is 19042.508, 20H2, not 2009 or similar.

Comment: Still, turn the option off, and at this point, wait (it will be about 6 months, so nothing near term).

Comment: Dev at this point would be 21H1 while Beta is 21H2 or later.  **Despite the fact it reported as 2004 it absolutely is not 2004 (20H1).**. Your simply using a build where the version hasn’t been changed to 20H1